# NodaTime Invalid DateTime.Kind for Instant.FromDateTimeUtc

Tags: c#, datetime, nodatime

I'm trying to get ahold of this timezone issue we are having. We would like to store all `DateTime`s in UTC, and then convert the `DateTime` to the user's timezone.

We decided to use NodaTime for this, as it seems like the right approach. However, we are experiencing an issue with it.

This is how we convert the `DateTime` to UTC (note - I hardcoded the `usersTimeZone` for now):

```
public static DateTime ConvertLocaltoUTC(this DateTime dateTime)
{
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(dateTime);

    IDateTimeZoneProvider timeZoneProvider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb;
    var usersTimezoneId = "Europe/Copenhagen";
    var usersTimezone = timeZoneProvider[usersTimezoneId];

    var zonedDbDateTime = usersTimezone.AtLeniently(localDateTime);
    var returnThis = zonedDbDateTime.ToDateTimeUtc();
    return zonedDbDateTime.ToDateTimeUtc();
}
```

And here is how we convert it back:

```
public static DateTime ConvertUTCtoLocal(this DateTime dateTime)
{
    Instant instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(dateTime);
    IDateTimeZoneProvider timeZoneProvider = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb;
    var usersTimezoneId = "Europe/Copenhagen"; //just an example
    var usersTimezone = timeZoneProvider[usersTimezoneId];
    var usersZonedDateTime = instant.InZone(usersTimezone);
    return usersZonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUnspecified();
}
```

However, when we convert it back to local time, it throws an exception:

> Argument Exception: Invalid DateTime.Kind for Instant.FromDateTimeUtc

at the first line of `ConvertUTCtoLocal()`.

An example of the `DateTime` could be: "9/18/2017 5:28:46 PM" - yes this has been through the `ConvertLocalToUTC` method.

Am I providing an incorrect format? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The value returned from `ZonedDateTime.ToDateTimeUtc()` should certainly be Utc, which is what `Instant.FromDateTimeUtc` requires. My guess is that the `DateTime` you're passing into `ConvertUTCtoLocal` isn't the result of calling `ConvertLocalToUTC`. However, I'd recommend avoiding using `DateTime` at all if you *possibly* can - use Noda Time types as far as possible.

Comment: (It would also be useful if you'd provide the version of Noda Time you're using.)

Comment: Please update this question with more information. As noted in both comments and answers, the problem lies elsewhere - which means at the moment, it's not a useful question.

Comment: Should we assume you're no longer interested in this question, as you haven't clarified it?

Comment: Hi John, I got it solved, it was because of corrupt data in my database. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: If it's a problem you can't reproduce, I'd argue it's not a useful question any more - I'd suggest deleting it. You probably can't while Matt's answer is present, but I suspect he'd be willing to delete his answer if the question's going to be deleted. (If you can find a case where the question *does* actually make sense, that's a different matter.)

Answer (score 13):

The exception you show:

> Argument Exception: Invalid DateTime.Kind for Instant.FromDateTimeUtc

Is thrown from this code:

> ```
> Instant instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(dateTime);
> ```

It means that `dateTime.Kind` needs to be `DateTimeKind.Utc` to be convertible to an `Instant`, and for whatever reason it is not.

If you look at the result of your `ConvertLocaltoUTC` method, you'll find that it *does* have `.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc`.

So, the problem lies elsewhere in your code, wherever you created the `dateTime` you're passing in to `ConvertUTCtoLocal`.

You may find the solution could be any of the following:

- You might need to call `DateTime.SpecifyKind` to set the kind to UTC, but be careful to only do this when your values are actually UTC and it's just not setting the kind.  For example, use this when loading a UTC-based `DateTime` from a database.
- You might need to call `.ToUniversalTime()`, but be careful to only do this if the machine's local time zone is relevant to your situation.  For example, do this in desktop or mobile apps where a UI control is picking a date, but you meant it to mean UTC instead of local time.
- You might need to change how you *parse* strings into `DateTime` values, such as by passing `DateTimeStyles.RoundTripKind` to a `DateTime.Parse` call (or any of its variants.  For example, do this if you are reading data from text, csv, etc.

If you want to avoid having to decide, don't write functions that take `DateTime` as input or give `DateTime` as output.  Instead, use `DateTimeOffset`, or use Noda-Time types like `Instant`, `LocalDateTime`, etc. as early as possible.

Answer (score 11):

This is what worked for me:

```
Instant instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(DateTime.SpecifyKind(datetime, DateTimeKind.Utc));
```